# Optimal algorithm to traverse all paths in the order of shortest path

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, search-algorithms

I have to generate all possible paths in a directed, acyclic weighted graph with edge costs. I also have to sort them in order of shortest path.

The simplest way that comes to mind is to do a depth-first search (DFS) for all paths, accumulating their edge costs as I traverse the paths, and then doing an NlogN sort on the result.

But I wondering if there is a better way to do this task. Are there any algorithms that could optimize this problem (combining DFS and a shortest path algorithm such as Dijkstra's maybe?).

Comment: Possibly Eppstein's k-th shortest path algorithm could be useful to you, you'd have to calculate the complexity though. However notice that a graph can have exponentially many paths, even between two vertices, so a polynomial (in the size of the graph) time algorithm is impossible.

Comment: Maybe to clarify: what is impossible in polytime is an algorithm that explicitly enumerates all paths sorted by length. What may possibly be possible is an algorithm that groups paths according to their length in sorted order and represents that grouping implicitly.

Comment: Thank you! This does correspond to the K shortest path routing problem. However, I wondering if I have a graph that is directed and acyclic (loop free) with a relatively small outdegree for each vertex (maximum 20 maybe...) and all possible paths have the same length is it still worth implementing Eppstein's algorithm, or is it better to use Dijkstra's algorithm generalized to find K shortest paths?

Comment: "all possible paths have the same length". how can that be? that is an unusual graph type. what is it? is it even possible except on some kind of trivial graphs? suggest you focus on describing carefully (1) the nature of the graphs and (2) the result of the algorithm... there are many standard algorithms in this area, if more than one can work, then one can just compare their performance empirically...

Comment: @Katie I don't know the answer to those questions. If I had to solve them, I would try to figure out the complexities of the approaches I have available.

Comment: If there are many many paths between a pair of vertices, do you really want to enumerate *all* of them? Is this problem theoretically motivated, or coming from some application?

Comment: An out-degree of 2 for each vertex is enough to make for an exponential number of paths, something like $2^{n/2}$

Comment: Have you worked through several small examples of what your input and output should be? Could you post one here? That can go a long way towards making your requirements clear and giving you insight into the problem.

Comment: when you say "all possible paths have the same length" in your comment are you talking about filtering all possible paths on the graph on the output?

Comment: @vzn: The graph is structured so that all vertices correspond to some group. The groups are ordered by size, and a path must travel to each group in this order (no backtracking). This way all paths will have the same size, but the contents of the path (vertex chosen from each group) can vary. As well, the edges between individual nodes have a cost. In this case I would want to find K shortest paths, sorted in order from least to greatest cost.

Comment: @Joe: You're right, if there are many, many paths, I would want perhaps only 50 of the best ones. This is for an application I am doing.

Comment: from your description it sounds like a _tree_ with supernodes that contain nodes...

Comment: If you really need only "few" shortest paths, Eppstein is probably the way to go (my remarks about real performance apply). I hope my answer sheds some light on the problem you originally asked; if there is something you want to ask about the k-shortest paths, feel free to open a new question. If there is more discussion to be had, please [take it to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science).

Answer (score 6):

The goal is to find all paths from $s$ to $t$ in a directed, acyclic graph with edge costs. Let $n$ the number of nodes, $m$ the number of edges and $p$ the number of $s$-$t$-paths. Let's look at what we have.

#### Naive enumeration

1. Use any graph traversal from $s$ to find all paths.
2. Sort them by length.

You can interleave the steps, but you'll end up with runtime $\Omega(n + p \log p)$ if there are $n$ nodes and $p$ paths.

Note that this algorithm is easy to parallelise.

#### Eppstein's Algorithm [1]

This one has runtime $O(m + n \log n + p)$ (from skimming the paper, I assume the bound is sharp, i.e. $\Theta$ holds). Note that paths are not represented explicitly.

I have no idea how well this algorithm can be parallelised.

#### Lower bounds

First of all, $p \in \Omega(2^n)$ in the worst case even in DAGs, see for instance this class of graphs:

[image]
<sup>[[source](https://github.com/akerbos/sesketches/blob/gh-pages/src/cs_19761.tikz)]</sup>

Note that all nodes have small out-degree and all paths have the same length.

Therefore, $p$ dominates any algorithm for this problem (in the worst case) if we can not make further assumptions.

When you go for a traversal over all paths, you clearly have runtime $\Omega(p)$.

#### Conclusion

Eppstein's algorithm is asymptotically optimal even in the setting you describe. However, asymptotic analysis at this level is rough and hides "extra" work that may or may not pay off in practice (since $n$ does *not* tend to infinity). The naive version may very well be competitive in an application, depending on $n$, $m$ and $p$, and maybe even structural features.

Another thing to keep in mind is that above figures are all worst-case but you are probably after average runtime on some specific input set².

TCS papers are unlikely to contain a rigorous analysis that helps you decide (and it's hard to do, too). Your question reads as if your goal is a real-world application, so I recommend a pragmatic approach. If the naive approach is too slow for you, try parallelising it. If that is still to slow, you can invest the time, implement Eppstein and run some tests.

---

1. [Finding the k Shortest Paths](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0097539795290477) by D. Eppstein (1998) [[preprint](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/Epp-SJC-98.pdf)]
2. My group developed a method for semi-automated average-case analysis and a tool to perform it. [Have a look](http://wwwagak.cs.uni-kl.de/malijan.html), maybe it can help you find out more about performance on your data.

Comment: This comment is late by a year and a half: isn't the number of paths in that graph in $\Omega(\sqrt{2}^n)$?

Comment: @G.Bach Right. I didn't explicitly state how many nodes there are, so let's say $2n+2$? ;D