# Finding all paths from s to t in linear time

Tags: algorithms, graphs, enumeration

I was looking at the [following algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/) which prints all the paths from node `s` to node `t` and I have some questions I don't understand

The basic idea is :

1. DFS-Visit(s)
2. Change current status to "currently visiting"
3. If neighbor is t -> print the path (from the stack trace or any way)
4. If not: DFS-Visit on neighbors
5. When done visiting neighbors: change status to "not-visited yet"

It seems like it's run-time is exponential, however - could I use the memorization technique like in dynamic programming to turn this into linear time ? since a lot of calculations are repeating

The example given in the algorithm is a DAG, but I couldn't find an regular graph that makes this algorithm fail.

It seems highly unlikely that this algorithm is possible in linear time on a regular graph... Wouldn't that help me to calculate shortest path from s to t in linear time ?

Comment: in a fully connected graph the number of paths from $s$ to $t$ will be $O(n!)$, kinda hard to get a linear time algorithm to print them all

Comment: @ratchetfreak Only if you consider simple paths only. Otherwise it's worse. (Also, $\Theta$!)

Comment: [Closely related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76174/98). Or [any of these](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Acs.stackexchange.com%20find%20all%20paths). Duplicate?

Comment: Finds *all* paths from $s$ to $t$ in $O(n)$? This means we could easily find the [longest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) in $O(n^3)$ simply by checking all pairs of nodes and all paths between them. So your guess about it not running in linear time on a regular graph is probably accurate. Although if you just have a DAG then it might be more reasonable because the longest path can be found in [linear time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths). So I would recommend sticking to DAGs.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm you describe cannot possibly be linear time for a DAG or general graph. Consider the following DAG on $n$ vertices $V = \{v_1, v_2, \ldots v_n\}$. Take a particular node $v_i$, for all $j > i$ add an edge $(v_i, v_j)$. This will create $\Theta(n^2)$ edges in this DAG. Note that a path from $v_1$ to $v_n$ can use any subset of nodes $\{v_2, v_3, \ldots v_{n-1}\}$. That is to say there are $2^{n-2}$ possible paths from $v_1$ to $v_n$. Clearly to print all these would take exponential time.

---

What you *can* do in linear time, is determine the subgraph that would contain all possible paths from $s$ to $t$. With a source $s$ in mind, we first check if it can reach $t$ (via DFS), if not then return an empty subgraph. Otherwise we check if $s$'s children $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots\}$ can reach $t$, this can be done recursively top-down or bottom-up if we start at $t$ and work backwards. Let's say $A$ is the set of nodes who are a descendant of $s$ and an ancestor of $t$. $A$ will also include $s$ and $t$ for obvious reasons. The subgraph we are interested will contain exactly the vertices in $A$. With this we can iterate through edges an include them as necessary, or we could even pick up edges long the way as we are determining which nodes are in $A$. This procedure overall will take $O(n + m)$. Of course, this is only interesting in a DAG unless $t$ or $s$ is an articulation point.